# reading passed data from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I've got 2 view controller, 
i want to pass data between them, in the first view controller i use this method to switch to other view controller and passing data :

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = [user username];
    NSString *userId = [user id];

    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
}
```

having this on view controller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *showEvent;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goQrcode;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *id;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
```

in the second view controller i have this method to read the variable and switch to another view controller:

```
- (IBAction)gotoEvents:(id)sender {

    events *events;
    events.first_name = _first_name;
    events.userid = _id;
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"events"];
    [self presentModalViewController:events animated:YES];
}
```

and this on my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *first_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *id;

- (IBAction)gotoEvents:(id)sender;
```

it says me 
property 'first_name' not found on object of type 'events'

Comment: Instead of retain use strong form first_name property...!

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If so, then you should be using [`prepareForSegue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
events *events = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"events"];
events.first_name = _first_name; //class name Should Start With capital letter and should use camel case for naming.
```

`events` should be named as `Events`, as it the class name